# Building an angular project

Tags: angular

I have create a sample project in angular with 2 components and it even has a backend nodejs

I want to deploy the angular project changing the base href to /name/

Can someone please share the deployment procedure and on what port does it run after deployment

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/deployment#building-and-serving-from-disk

Comment: i need a sample... i have referred all these links... but my question is on which port the application will run after deployment

Answer (score 0):

- First you have to run   ng build --prod --base-href /name/
- After that you will find your project inside **dist** folder
- To Deploy if you have server you have to install Apache server after
  that we will find folder inside /var/www/html/
- Put the **DIST** folder content inside **/var/www/html/** and you can
  access it through the port **80** normally